# Responsive Product Listing with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create the below for a product listing section of a test learner website I am making.

The hope image is for desktop and the lower for mobile.

[image]

I am tried to use a table to get this to work but I can't wrap my head around it (someone told me it might help). I would rather use bootstrap to get this to work but I can't understand the best way of getting the different Div's to move and stack the way I want them to. If anyone can help that would be amazing!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">Div 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12">Div 2</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">Div 3</div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 visible-xs">Div 4</div> 
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're amazing, I also understand what you did now, you have created Div's based on screensize and hidden the last Div 4 depending on screen size? Thanks a lot for that

Comment: Yes. In this case I think the only way is to print div 4 twice and in the first case make only visible for mobile and in the second case make hidden for mobile (and visible for other sizes).